# What does "on a level flat" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

This is the context from [an English translation](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/182/crime-and-punishment/3393/part-1-chapter-2/) of *Crime And Punishment* by Dostoevsky

"The little town stood on **a level flat** as bare as the hand, not even a willow near it"

One of the definitions for the word "level" listed by Longman is:
"a floor or area of ground that is at a particular height, especially when you can go up or down to other floors or areas"

But still, it's weird that the adjective flat is before the noun(it's a dated translation-maybe it was allowed in the past to put it in that order ?). What does it mean exactly?

Comment: Flat is a noun here: a level surface of land. [Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flat). Repetition for emphasis.

Answer (score 3):

It may be the age of the translation, but I don't think the English works well here.  A comma may help.

A "level" can mean "a flat tract of land".  (This is a rarer sense, nowadays mostly in proper nouns like "The Somerset Levels", but here it is a common noun) But then the translator seems to get slightly mixed up.  Perhaps there is noun sense of "flat", or a "level flat" is an open tract of land.

The original makes the meaning clear:

> The town stood *in the open*, as if in the palm of the hand, without even willow around it.

(It seems normal in Russia to have some kind of fence, hedge or wall around a town, but this town was, exceptionally,  стоит открыто (standing openly), как на ладони (as on the palm). I think this latter phrase is a Russian idiom meaning "In full view of everyone")

Comment: What do you mean by "the original"?  Is this translation you've provided your own? Wherever it came from, it's certainly much more sensible than the original.

Comment: Google translate! (Slightly edited)

Comment: I answer most of the "Crime and Punishment" questions by referring to the text on Wikisource, and using Google translate.  There is a bit of a cheat here, since GT was almost certainly trained on texts including Crime and Punishment...

Comment: Interesting.  My knowledge of Google Translate is definitely out of date.  I remember hearing it was seeded with mostly legal documents, treaties, or things that the UN publishes in many languages.  But that wouldn't account for why some languages work so much better than others.

Comment: "The Outcasts of Poker Flat" (1869) is a short story written by Bret Harte.

Comment: Damn, I wish I didn't like this convoluted English translation of the book. Thanks for the answers. It's nice to learn something new about Google Translator(i was underestimating it :)).

Comment: For use in learning English, one of the modern translations is better. Of course not free, but not expensive.  Garnett's translation is generally well done, but it is known to have flaws. She worked very fast.